# Will this GPU fit my PC?

Tags: graphics-cards

Will THIS GPU: [http://www.amazon.com/EVGA-GeForce-750Ti-GDDR5-Graphics/dp/B00IDG3IDO](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00IDG3IDO), fit my PC: http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c04803166?

I know my PC has PCI express 3.0, which I think that gpu needs. If not, what's a good GPU thats around ~$120 that's compatible? And what PSU will I need?

If that doesn't fit, here are some requirements if u want to suggest something:
- Must support my PC(ofc)
- Must be able to run Minecraft at 60~ fps at medium settings
- No intel.
- It must be $130 or below
- It must be able to run Cities Skylines at 10~ fps at medium settings

Comment: Welcome to Hardware Recommendations. Here we recommend hardware when you give us your requirements. Unfortunately, this makes "Will this work" type questions somewhat off topic. If you could post all your requirements, that would be better.

Comment: Which stack exchange board would be good for 'will this work' questions?

Comment: Now that you've added requirements, it seems alright. I'm retracting my close vote.

Comment: Can you get out a ruler and try and measure how long the card can be? HP gives the outside dimensions, but not the inside ones. The GPU goes in the long slot that doesn't have RAM in it.

Comment: I've never opened up a pc before. So, no. Sorry :/

Comment: How do you suppose you're going to put the GPU in?

Comment: Get someone else to.

Comment: Well, would you rather get someone else to measure it now, or after returning the card you bought because it won't fit?

Answer (score 1):

As far as hardware compatibility goes, you're fine. The 750 Ti is indeed PCI-E 3.0, and the motherboard in the model you linked supports it. So since the motherboard slot and the GPU are both PCI-E 3.0 x16, the GPU should fit just fine. The dimensions of the card are 6.70" x 4.38" if you'd like to measure for yourself. It's also a dual-slot card, so keep in mind that you won't be able to use the slot below the PCI-E slot.

Replacing the GPU is extremely simple, and there are tons of YouTube videos on it. There's really no need to get someone to do it for you, unless it's a friend or family member that would do it for free.